# Can't find the bases of the eigenspaces

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics

I have this matrix:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 2 \\
    0 & 3 & -1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

I found the eigenvalues which are $2$ and $-3$.

So I substituted $2$ in the matrix:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & -2 & 2 \\
    0 & 3 & -3 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

The sytem is:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
v_2=0 \\ 
-2v_2 +2v_3=0 \\ 
3v_2-3v_3=0
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Which becomes...

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
v_2=0 \\ 
v_2=v_3 \\ 
v_2=v_3
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

So I suppose that the bases of the eigenspace of the eigenvalue $2$ is $(0,0,0)$, is that possible?

Eigenspace for the eigenvalue $-3$:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    5 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 3 & 2 \\
    0 & 3 & 2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
5v_1+v_2=0 \\ 
3v_2+2v_3=0 \\ 
3v_2+2v_3=0
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
v_1=-(v_2)/5 \\ 
v_2=-(2/3) v_3 \\ 
v_3=-(3/2)v_2
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

So the base I found is $(-1/5, -2/3, -3/2)$

Comment: Keep in mind that an eigenvector will never be the null vector.

Comment: The dimension of an eigenspace is always greater than zero, meaning you should always be able to find a non-zero vector $\vec{v}$ such that $A\vec{v} = \lambda \vec{v}$ for your eigenvalue $\lambda$ and matrix $A$. In your case, $v_1$ is freely chosen, so assign some parameter $s \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $\vec{v} = s\cdot (1,0,0)$ is always an eigenvector.

Comment: Note on formatting: if you want to have brackets around the matrix, use \begin{pmatrix} instead of \begin{matrix}.

Comment: or... in keeping with John Doe, use `\begin{bmatrix}....................... \end{bmatrix}`.  Perhaps you've noticed that using huge parenthesis to surround a matrix around each of its side, we use {pmatrix} (p for parentheses.)  To use square brackets, we use {bmatrix) (b for bracket.)  Using square brackets, we get this image of your first matrix: \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 2 \\
    0 & 3 & -1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible; remember that by the definition of eigenvectors we are looking for no trivial solution of $(A-2I)x=0$.

Indeed note that from the system you obtain $v_1\neq0,\;$ thus an eigenvector is $\;(1,0,0),\;$ as you can directly verify from the $(A-2I)$ matrix.

Comment: So the base for the eigenvalue $2$ is $(1,0,0)$? Why is $v_1≠0$ and why is $v_1=1$?

Comment: @MarkB (1,0,0) is an eigenvector of $\lambda=2$. You can easily derive it form the system you only obtain $v_2=v_3=0$ but $v_1$ is free. Thus everi vector (a,0,0) in an eigenvalue for $\lambda=2$.

Comment: Is a eigenvector the same as a base of a eigenspace?

Comment: @MarkB an eigenvector is a basis vector for the eigenspace, teh dimension can be greater than 1

Comment: @MarkB in this case it is correct since the eigenspace has dimension 1

Comment: I can't understand why $v_1$ is $1$ and not for example $2$ or $3$ or whatever number

Comment: @MarkB you can choose any value, you have infinite eigenvectors for $\lambda=2$ (always they are infinitely many)

Comment: @MarkB It can be any of those. Any nonzero scalar multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector. However, it’s usually most convenient for a basis to set it to $1$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. How can I find if this matrix is diagonalizable?

Comment: @MarkB if you find three distinct eigenvalues you can diagonalize since you can find a basis of eigenvectors

Comment: otherwise if you have two equal eigenvalues you need to verify the dimension of the related eigenspace, if you can find two distinct eigenvectors for that eigenvalues you can diagonalize

Comment: @MarkB if you have only one eigenvalue (with algebraic multiplicity 3) you can diagonalize only if the related eigenspace has dimension 3 (that is if the geometric multiplicity is 3)

Comment: For the eigenvalue $-3$ the base is $(-1/5;-2/3;-3/2)$ ?

Comment: @MarkB You can check it directly form (A+3I)x=0, it seems don't work, maybe (-1/5;1;-3/2)?

Comment: I actually checked it but I'm not sure if it's the correct base.

Comment: @MarkB It is not an eigenvector for -3, you can check it directly calculating  (A+3I)(-1/5;-2/3;-3/2) which is not 0, an eigenvector for -3 is (-1/5;1;-3/2)

Comment: I edited the original post. Please check my calculations.

Comment: Note that $v_2=-(2/3) v_3=-(2/3)(-3/2)=1$